# How to make a custom route for users? And how to add hooks to it?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I'm trying to add a route /me to get user authenticated information. This is what I have at my files.
I've tried adding a route /me at users.services file, but I'm getting this error: "error:  MethodNotAllowed: Method `find` is not supported by this endpoint."

I want to get response with a user object (based on token) to a GET method to route '/me'.

**users.service.js**

```
// Initializes the `users` service on path `/users`
const createService = require('feathers-sequelize');
const createModel = require('../../models/users.model');
const hooks = require('./users.hooks');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    name: 'users',
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  // Initialize our service with any options it requires
  app.use('/users', createService(options));

  app.use('/me', {
      get(id, params) {
        return Promise.resolve([
          {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Message 1'
          }
        ])
      }
  })

  // Get our initialized service so that we can register hooks and filters
  const service = app.service('users');

  service.hooks(hooks);
};
```

**users.hooks.js**

```
const { authenticate } = require('@feathersjs/authentication').hooks;

const {
  hashPassword, protect
} = require('@feathersjs/authentication-local').hooks;

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ ],
    find: [ authenticate('jwt') ],
    get: [],
    create: [ hashPassword() ],
    update: [ hashPassword() ],
    patch: [ hashPassword() ],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [ 
      // Make sure the password field is never sent to the client
      // Always must be the last hook
      protect('password')
    ],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

**users.model.js**

```
// See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/
// for more of what you can do here.
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const users = sequelizeClient.define('users', {

    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },


  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  users.associate = function (models) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    // Define associations here
    // See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/
  };

  return users;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did through

```
  app.use('/me', {
      get(id, params) {
        return Promise.resolve([
          {
            id: 1,
            text: 'Message 1'
          }
        ])
      }
  })
```

Was implement routes for `/me/:id`. The [find](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#expressrest) method is what runs for the base route of `/me`.

I don't think a separate service is really necessary though. An easier solution would be to use a `before` `all` hook that changes the id if you are accessing `/users/me`:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return async context => {
    if(context.id === 'me') {
      context.id = context.params.user._id;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did what you told me, using a hook but context.params.user is undefined. How do I populate that data?

Comment: The `authenticate('jwt')` does that for you. You probably don't just want to use it before `find` like in you current `users.hooks.js` but before `all`.

Comment: @Daff how could you change the id?